# CardView Spacing between each separate card is non-existent

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, cardview

Below you will find a screenshot. As you can see, between each card in my CardView, there is no spacing (They are bunched up below one another) [The CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk3Yi.png)

I am trying to get a spacing between each separate card. (Each card contains an image, an item number and a boolean)

I have tried `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` and adding padding manually.

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

recyclerview_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#e6e6e6">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent of `CardView`:  `LinearLayout` define `android:layout_margin="XXdp"`. That might help.

Comment: I did so, however nothing changed.

Comment: And you are sure, that this is `margin`, not `padding`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Just to confirm here's the edited code.



`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">`

Comment: My mistake, it should `android:layout_margin`.

Comment: So, what exactly should I do? I have, `android:layout_margin="10dp"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define margin top inside widget.CardView:

```
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
```

And You don't need the linear layout.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by, "You don't need the linear layout" as I am not sure which one you are talking about, and how I'd get around it.

Comment: You have just one LinearLayout. You don't need it. So delete it and add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" inside CardView

Comment: I see what you mean. However once again, nothing changed.

https://hastebin.com/gojeyupiri.xml